# How to dismiss a viewController from another location

Tags: ios, swift

I have a file where i define how a controller should look and define constraints and other things, here i also declare a addtarget on one of buttons like below

```
 nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and define the method, now every thing works but on the controller page the code to dismiss the modalView does not respond, some how any variation of dismiss code called from view file does not work on the controller , ever thing else works but not dismiss

```
@objc func nextButtonTapped()
       {


           let index = childController.currentIndex
               print(index)
               switch index {
               case 0...1:

                   childController.forwardPage()


               case 2:
                
                //  dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                //diss.getDisMiss()
                self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                  
                
               default:
                   break

               }
        
        updateUI()


       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is.

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```